# Generic inherited type restriction in C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have an inelegant solution for what I need, but am looking for an elegant solution to replace it.

The following code doesn't compile, but represents what I would like to do:

```
interface IWebService
{
}

abstract class BaseClient<T>
{
}

class SpecializedClient : BaseClient<IWebService>
{
}

class ClientHelper<T> where T : BaseClient<*>
{
}
```

Where the `T` in `ClientHelper<T>` is any class that extends `BaseClient` regardless of the templated type passed in.

The inelegant solution I found is:

```
class ClientHelper<T, U> where T : BaseClient<U> {}
```

The reason this becomes inelegant is my project ends up with a class similar to:

```
class MyClass<A, B, C, D, E, F, G> where A  : MyBaseClass<B, C, D, E, F, G>
```

All the way down to the base class that takes a single type.  Is this simply the cost of having a complex inheritance tree of generic classes or is there a simpler way to do this while retaining type restrictions on the templated types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "inelegant" solution is the right one if the public interface of BaseClient exposes it's generic type parameter in any way.

So assuming `BaseClient` is **not** as you defined it:

```
abstract class BaseClient<T>
{
   //Something about T here
}
```

Then T is part of the public interface contract of `BaseClient`, and therefore part of the public interface contract of `ClientHelper` (again, assuming that `BaseClient<U>` is exposed via the interface of ClientHelper).

On the other hand, let's assume it actually is as your example puts it:

```
abstract class BaseClient<T>
{
   //Nothing about T here
}
```

In that case, you can do:

```
interface IBaseClient
{
   //Nothing about T here
}

abstract class BaseClient<T> : IBaseClient
{ 
    // Whatever you like here
}
```

and `ClientHelper` becomes:

```
class ClientHelper<T> where T : IBaseClient
{
}
```

Comment: The interface might work for part of it as some of my classes don't publicly expose `T` they simply use it internally. I'll take any simplification I can get as it is beginning to become unwieldy.

Comment: That simplified all cases where I have `Class<T>` where `T` is never publicly exposed. Simple, yet so obvious I couldn't see it. :-) It cut out roughly half of the types that need to be forwarded around.

Comment: Cool.  Glad it worked out for you.  You might also be able to eliminate the some additional generic parameters if you can generalize all of the ***operations*** for a given `T` (methods, properties, events, and fields) that are not type-dependent into interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

One option seems to be:

```
interface IWebService
{
}

interface IClient<out T>
{
}

abstract class BaseClient<T> : IClient<T>
{
}

class SpecializedClient : BaseClient<IWebService>
{
}

class ClientHelper<T> where T : IClient<object>
{
}
```

However that will only work if you `BaseClient` only returns `T` and never accepts it.